# Matlab - Printing 2D vector

Tags: matlab

I need some help. Basically, I have a large dataset that I have split into blocks, now, I need to print the blocks individually instead of printing the whole entire block.

Here is my code:

```
function f = printData()

  data('FILE_NAME');
  blockeddata = blocks(data, 600, 200);
  f = blockeddata;
end
```

I just need to print each block separately. Ideas anyone?

Here's the function:

```
function f = blocks(v, N, M)

   n = length(v);
   maxblockstart = n - N + 1;
   lastblockstart = maxblockstart - mod(maxblockstart-1 , M);

   % numblocks = (lastblockstart-1)/M + 1
   numblocks = (lastblockstart-1)/M + 1;

   %f = zeros(numblocks,N);

   for i = 1:numblocks
     for j = 1:N
       f(i,j) = v((i-1)*M+j);
     end
   end
```

Comment: could you please clarify the blocks function you are using? I don't believe i've encountered it before

Comment: @AK4749 Updated - Hope you can help :)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understand the problem, but how about sending N and M to print()? From the quick looks of it, you already have the functionality. You just need to modify your print function to take N and M.

So basically, add N and M to print() and change 600 and 200 to N and M respectively. Then call print with 600 and 200 (or whatever you like) as your input.

Hope it helped :D

Comment: Hey, I fixed it (Kinda) I just printed it as 1D rather than 2D using f = blockeddata(:); :D